# Creating and Organizing Registry Backups

Tags: beginner, batch

I've never messed with batch really so I'm trying to introduce myself. I made this to back up all registry data and organize it like this:

- RegBackup

  - November

    - 11-27-2020

      - [Registry Files]
    - 11-28-2020

      - [Registry Files]
- Backup.bat

The script is:

```
@echo off

Rem set bat location as CD
cd /D "%~dp0"
Rem open explorer to CD
explorer "%~dp0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
Rem set Month string
set m=100
for %%m in (January 
    February 
    March 
    April 
    May 
    June 
    July 
    August 
    September 
    October 
    November 
    December
) do (
  set /a m+=1
  set month[!m:~-2!]=%%m
)
set monthNow=%date:~3,3%
set monthNow=%monthNow: =%
set monthName=!month[%monthNow%]!
Rem create/enter Month string directory
if not exist %monthName% mkdir %monthName%
Rem set for current date in mm-dd-yyyy format
SET Today=%date:~-10,2%"-"%date:~7,2%"-"%date:~-4,4%
Rem create/enter mm-dd-yyyy directory
if not exist %Today% mkdir %Today%
cd %Today%
Rem save registry files into mm-dd-yyyy
REG SAVE HKLM\SOFTWARE SOFTWARE
REG SAVE HKLM\SYSTEM SYSTEM
REG SAVE HKU\.DEFAULT DEFAULT
REG SAVE HKLM\SECURITY SECURITY
REG SAVE HKLM\SAM SAM
Rem go up a folder. aka to .bat location directory
cd ..
Rem move mm-dd-yyyy into Month directory/already exists, delete new, pretend never happened.
move %Today% %monthName% || rmdir /Q /S %Today%
```

I added some remarks just to more or less explain whats going on, but I feel like there's an easier way than creating `%Today%`, filling it, and *then* moving the whole thing with all its contents, so I was hoping I could get some feedback on any ways I could improve, or just pointing me in the direction would be great. I know windows has a built in backup I could use but that's no fun :p.

(I hope I'm posting properly, I tried to make sure to follow the posting rules, I'm sorry if I messed something up!)

Comment: Oh dear. Why not PowerShell, if you have to go down this route?